# How to get a question url in SEDE?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I know I can use the `[Post Link]` option in a query to get a hyperlink to a post.

However, when writing the CSV file, this does not actually write out the post url (similar to the WebsiteUrl field in the users table).

Is there a convenient way to get the post url itself, so when you write a CSV file it places the hyperlink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use syntax such as:

```
 'http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/' + CAST(p.Id AS nvarchar) As PostUrl
```

Or, better, adding a parameter:

```
'##site##/questions/' + CAST(p.Id AS nvarchar) As PostUrl
```

Comment: For the normal tabular output, [you can also use](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) `'site://questions/' + CAST(p.Id AS nvarchar)`, but apparently the `site://` prefix doesn't get replaced by the site name in CSV output. :(